# Evaluate the given double integral in the given region $D$.

Tags: integration

$$\iint(x^3+2)\,dA$$
$$D:\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2\le25\}$$
Should I use polar coordinates?

Comment: Did you try to use them?

Comment: yes. definitely use polar coordinates because notice $x^2+y^2\le5^2$ is the equation of a circle

Comment: I didn't use it because I wasn't sure. I drew the region. if I'm not mistaken it's a circle. Its radius is 5. When the region is circle, need i to use polar coordinates? Or not.

Comment: need I to write x=r.cosθ? and instead of dxdy can i write rdrdθ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easier solution: $$\require{cancel} \iint_D (x^3+2)\,{\rm d}A = \cancelto{0}{\iint_D x^3\,{\rm d}A} + 2\,{\rm area}(D)= 2 (\pi \cdot 5^2) = 50\pi.$$The integral of $x^3$ vanishes by symmetry of $(x,y)\mapsto x^3$ and the fact that $D$ is symmetric about the $y$ axis.

Answer (score 1):

Using polar coordinates you get

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^5(r^3\cos^3\theta+2)r\,dr\,d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}5^4\cos^3\theta+25\,d\theta=\left.5^4\left(\sin\theta-\frac{\sin^3 \theta}{3}\right)+25\theta\right|_0^{2\pi}=\boxed{50\,\pi}$$

Comment: thank you so much...